# How to set the same edge weight in a graph using a loop using Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

As the Boost documentation might include this but it seems very hard to understand those parameters in my knowledge of programming, from the documentation and some examples I came up with a question: What If I want to set all edge weights to be the same (for example: 1)?

Obviously I don't want to use

```
boost::add_edge(vertice1, vertice2, weight, graph);
```

for endless time if the graph is big enough to have many many edges.

It would be appreciate if someone can offer some examples to run.

Comment: where's your code...

Comment: Also "for endless time if the graph is big enough to have many many vertices" - you were talking about edge weights, so worry only about the edges.

Comment: @sehe Well "many many edges" also stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show any code (except what you don't want to write...).

The exact form would depend on that. E.g. here's with a bundled weight property:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8f7dc5252009d5f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

struct VertexProps { };
struct EdgeProps { double weight; };

int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProps, EdgeProps> g;

    for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        g[ed].weight = 1.0;
}
```

Of course, you could basically achieve the same with a proper default:

```
struct EdgeProps { double weight = 1.0; };
```

and you wouldn't even need a loop.

---

#### With a property map

First adapting from the above:

```
auto weight_map = get(&EdgeProps::weight, g);

for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
    weight_map[ed] = 1.0;
```

#### Interior  Properties

Which would also work with something else than bundled properties:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b436e761acfebf90)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> > g;

    auto weight_map = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

    for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        weight_map[ed] = 1.0;
}
```

#### External Properties

Or with completely external properties

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;
Graph g(10);

std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, double> weights;
auto weight_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(weights);

for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
    weight_map[ed] = 1.0;
```

### Lastly

If the goal is just to have identical weights, just use a constant map:

```
auto weight_map = boost::make_constant_property<Graph::edge_descriptor>(1.0);
```

Comment: no... it's not that I don't want to write, is I don't know how to write..

Comment: I was referring to your own statement - your question literally says "Obviously I don't want to use [code you _do_ know how to write]". Was my answer helpful in any way?

Comment: For the first one after I set default property on the edge weight after that If I want to add edges it would just be `add_edge(vertice1, vertice2, graph)`?